# HP ALM (Microfocus): "SMART_REPOSITORY_LOGICALFILE" column "SRLF_PARENT_PATH"

Tags: hp-alm, microfocus

In `HP ALM` Table `SMART_REPOSITORY_LOGICALFILE` there is a column `SRLF_PARENT_PATH`

I need to know where the path segments come from since I'm experiencing massive issues after upgrade...

Sample:

```
.\hist\REQ\0000\0042\0123\4567\3
```

I only know where the last two segments are coming from:

- "4567" is the Requirement Id
- "3" is the version number of the requirement

But where does `0000\0042\0123` come from?

There is no physical path like that on the entire server...

Answer (score 0):

Prior to ALM 11.0 the path of the repository content was exposed and the logical path matched the physical path. Since 11.0 they started using smart repository. Those two segments are the nested directory levels in the logical path(not the physical OS one). Note that there is a direct access to the logical path via FTP which you can activate via a Site Admin parameter using the FTP_PORT param.